# How to use arguments of exposed page filters as contextual filter for block on that same page

Tags: views

I have a Views map *page* which correctly shows markers filtered by Destination and Category through exposed filter criteria of the kind:
/en/full-map?field_geographic_hierarchy_tid%5B%5D=**18**&field_location_type_tid%5B%5D=**1**

Under that map I want to place a *block* that uses the provided term-ID's (in bold) to create a LIST that shows the same selection as on the map.

My guess was to achieve that through "Contextual Filters" (*block* is same view as *page*). 
I have tried several options under "configure contextual filter - when filter value is NOT available" but couldn't work it out.

How can I tell Contextual Filters to just read those term-ID's after the:

**?field_geographic_hierarchy_tid%5B%5D=**

and **&field_location_type_tid%5B%5D=** ??

Is this the right strategy or should Relationships be considered (as well)?